# How to find a point X between two Vector3 in Unity3d

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, unityscript

OK, it's not easy explain me so i will use an image.

I have the following problem :

### I have a line between two points A and B. I need to calculate the coordinates of the 'X' point knowing that it is perpendicular to the point C.

[image: Editor situation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity has a built-in function for this : [Vector3.Project](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Project.html)

```
Vector3 AB = B - A ;
Vector3 AC = C - A ;
Vector3 AX = Vector3.Project(AC, AB);
Vector3 X = AX + A ; //How say Lutzl works!
```

Comment: Hell I didn't know that! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Correct the syntax into the code to "Vector3.Project" instead "Vector3Project" :)

Comment: Check if the last line shouldn't be `X=A+AX`, as usually,`AX = X-A`